# Change the tile image of a shortcut tile pinned on the metro desktop

Tags: windows-8

we have created a tile shortcut, which is similar to pinning the IE shortcuts on the screen. We have done this through code. We want an image should come on this tile. How do we add image to such a shortcut tile. we are running an exe first on windows 7 desktop mode and then making the pin to screen event click using the shell scripting. the tile is similar to any internet address pinned on the desktop

Answer (score 1):

See [this sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178)...

The basic code you will need to achieve this is as follows...

```
Uri logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/squareTile-sdk.png"); 
Uri smallLogo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/smallTile-sdk.png"); 
string tileActivationArguments = MainPage.logoSecondaryTileId + " WasPinnedAt=" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString(); 
SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(MainPage.logoSecondaryTileId, 
   "Title text shown on the tile", 
   "Name of the tile the user sees when searching for the tile", 
   tileActivationArguments, 
   TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo, 
   logo); 
secondaryTile.ForegroundText = ForegroundText.Dark; 
secondaryTile.SmallLogo = smallLogo; 
bool isPinned = await await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```